# The intersection of subgroup and normal subgroup: the greatest common divisor?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Is the order of intersection of subgroup $H$ and normal subgroup $N$ of group $G$ the greatest common divisor of $\lvert H\rvert$ and $\lvert N\rvert$?

Comment: I guess it is the maximal order possible but it's not necessarily true

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Take $2$ distinct elements out of Kleins group of $4$ unequal  the identity. The subgroups that they genenerate both have order $2$ but the intersection only contains the identity.

Answer (score 1):

You can also take $H$ and $N$ to be two subgroups of order $4$ in $Q_{8}$. Then both $H$ and $N$ are normal and their intersection is the center which has two elements and so the result fails in this case.

Alternatively, take $N = V_{4}$ - which is the subgroup made by cycles of the type (2, 2) and so it is normal in $S_{4}$. Then let $H$ be any other subgroup of order 4. Then the intersection has two elements once again and you get a contradiction.